# C# Parent and Child class - picking the child out of a parent class

Tags: c#

Does anyone know, why this underlines(error) Suit (Child class of Stock)in the part that says "stock is Suit"?

```
//Picking Suit out of the Stock
        public System.Collections.ArrayList Suit()
        {
            System.Collections.ArrayList array = new System.Collections.ArrayList(); //looping through Persons array
            foreach (Stock stock in allStock)//using code snippets
            {
                if (stock is Suit) //if it is a customer, display value, if not, return to the array list
                {
                    array.Add(stock);
                }
            }
            return array;
        }
```

Comment: What is the error it shows?

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList`? It's so 2002. There are far better collections now - try `List<Suit>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method has the same name as your child class: `Suit`. This is the error.

This method should be renamed (and can be refactored using LINQ) like this:

```
public List<Suit> GetSuits()
{
    return 
        allStock
            .Select(stock => stock as Suit)
            .Where(suit => suit != null)
            .ToList();
}
```

Or without LINQ:

```
public List<Suit> GetSuits()
{
    var result = new List<Suit>();

    foreach (Stock stock in allStock)
    {
        var suit = stock as Suit;
        if (suit != null)
        {
            result.Add(suit);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```